# How to make posts unqueryable/unpublish posts where ACF relationship field is an unpublished post?

Tags: wp-query, loop, filters, advanced-custom-fields, query-posts

I am using ACF Pro to make a relationship between two custom post types.

One CPT is a *thing* and the other is a *Container of Things*. I need to solve the issue of *things* within a *container of things* being visible when *container of things* has been unpublished.

I *think* using something like [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to filter all queries that happen before any results get returned is the solution, but I am not 100% sure. Or perhaps some way to unpublish all *things* when the relationship field post becomes unpublished.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: ACF dev support questions and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check out `pre_post_update`.

Use `pre_post_update` to check for a post update within your custom post type *Container of Things*. Check for your conditions. Then, get the connected *Things* and use `wp_update_post` to unpublish these posts.

Comment: Okay, I like this angle. Thank you for your input. I will try to implement something along these lines.